# Mailchimp API 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I got various Websites that are accessing to Mailchimp API to subscribe addresses into Mailchimp Lists and getting Entries from there.

A few days ago, the API Calls are canceled due to a 403 Forbidden (Generic Error) when accessing a resource.

### Error message:

```
Array
    (
[headers] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXX/members?
        [content_type] => text/html
        [http_code] => 403
        [header_size] => 170
        [request_size] => 312
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 0
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0,292724
        [namelookup_time] => 0,004255
        [connect_time] => 0,018535
        [pretransfer_time] => 0,161542
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 162
        [speed_download] => 553
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 162
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 0,292685
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [redirect_url] => 
        [primary_ip] => 104.83.97.93
        [certinfo] => Array
            (
            )

        [primary_port] => 443
        [local_ip] => 80.74.145.2
        [local_port] => 36488
        [request_header] => GET /3.0/lists/XXXXXXX/members? HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: DrewM/MailChimp-API/3.0 (github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)
Host: us8.api.mailchimp.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Authorization: apikey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-us8


    )

[httpHeaders] => Array
    (
        [Server] => openresty
        [Content-Type] => text/html
        [Content-Length] => 162
        [Vary] => Accept-Encoding
        [Date] => Tue, 05 Jun 2018 13:58:16 GMT
        [Connection] => close
    )

[body] => <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

)
```

---

Is Mailchimp blacklisting IP adresses? Because, when a clone the website to another IP Host the authentication works correctly.

If yes, is it possible to resolve the blacklisting, or at least monitor that issue?

Comment: In my case, I had server cache enabled caching first request what was end-point with wrong data center prefix